# Android Studio 2.3.3 - Error class EditText while inflating xml file in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-edittext, build.gradle, android-inflate

Good evening..!

**I got Error class EditText while inflating xml file of Fragment when I ran my app in Samsung Galaxy Tab.**
But, this inflation error doesn't occur in other Tabs -  Micromax and Lenovo.

Even though, I downgraded the gradle version from 2.3.3 to 2.1.0 as said in the previous discussions
 ([Android Error inflating class EditText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38103414/android-error-inflating-class-edittext)) , the got the 
error shown in the below image.

I am not getting what is the exact issue.

[image]

Thank you in advance..!

Comment: You can restart your android studio once,then Make sure that your Internet connected.

Comment: Go to file->Invalidate and Restart, your android studio,because if you update major version of sdk you have to restart your Android studio.